# How can I let android emulator talk to the localhost?

Tags: python, android, android-emulator, webview

I'm running an android app on the emulator. This app tries to load a html file using the webview api.

I also have a simple http server running on the same computer under the directory where I want to serve the request using the following python command:

*python -m SimpleHTTPServer 800*

However, I couldn't access this link through either the app or the browser on the emulator:

*http://localhost:800/demo.html*

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use address 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost.

Comment: Yup. More info on networking with the Android emulator is up at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking .

Answer (score 0):

localhost is a short-cut to tell the "whatever" to talk to itself. So, you are telling the emulator to look for a web server running in the emulator.

Instead of trying to connect to localhost, look up the IP for your computer and use that instead.

Comment: in general, yes, e.g. if you're using a virtual machine. but in the android emulator it's hardcoded `10.0.2.2` as Piva said

Answer (score 0):

Actually localhost refers to the emulators directory itself.

Use your system ip to access the link

Answer (score -2):

Best solution is not to use emulator at all. Its slow and full of bugs. Get your employer to buy a device or two.

Comment: Far from 'best' solution. What if you are a freelancer and don't have the budget to buy "a device or two"?